# Invalid syntax error python 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error, python-2.6

Can anyone please correct me this code to be compatible with python 2.6

it's working fine with python >=2.7

```
dict = {k:v for k, v in dict.items() if v[1]<=min_len}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: *What* syntax error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 2.6 does not have dictionary comprehensions. Try this instead:

```
d = dict([(k,v) for k, v in d.items() if v[1]<=min_len])
```

and don't assign to a variable called `dict` or you will hide the builtin type that you need to call to construct the `dict` here.